# How to make List of File in dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

Can we make List of File in flutter?
I have a function which I have called multiple times and later set a value. But when I make List of File and try to store data I get error saying RangeError.
This is my code

```
 File? _displayImage;
  List<File> _displayImageList = [];
  Future<void> saveNetworkFileToLocalDirectory(String fileSrcUrl, int j) async {
    var response = await http.get(Uri.parse(fileSrcUrl));
    Directory documentsDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();

    String filePath =
        join(documentsDirectory.path, getFileNameFromUrl(fileSrcUrl));
    File file = File(filePath);
    log(file.toString() + ' file');
    log(filePath + ' file path');
    await file.writeAsBytes(response.bodyBytes);

    setState(() {
      _displayImage = file;
      log('j value ' + j.toString());
      _displayImageList[j] = file;
    });
```

Comment: You can't use the `[]` operator in `List` to grow the list (add a new member to it). You can instead use `_displayImageList.add(file)` to grow the list in size by one and add a new entry at the end of the list. You can also look at `insert` to insert at specific indexes if you need to be able to insert in the middle of something: https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.17.5/dart-core/List/insert.html . But you can't use that to insert at arbitrary positions.

Comment: If you need to save `File` for an arbitrary `j` value, you can consider using a `Map<int, File>` instead.

Comment: That really saved me from a lot of trouble. :)

Answer (score 0):

`List` in Dart does not allow for arbitrary position of elements, but are instead a collection of objects that starts from index position 0 and to index `length - 1` where `length` are the amount of elements in the `List`.

So to insert an element in `List`, we need to grow it by using one of the methods that `List` provides to do so. E.g. we can use `add()` to grow the list by one in size while adding an element to the end of the `List`.

If you need to insert elements with arbitrary "positions", you should instead consider using a `Map<int, File>` in your case since you can then map a given `j` value to a `File` object.

You do, however, need to be aware that the default `Map` in Dart are ordered by the insertion time of the element (newest entry = last "position" when iterating over the keys). If you need to order the elements based on the key, we can consider using something like `SplayTreeMap` which automatically sorts entries based on the `key` object when inserting the element:

https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.17.5/dart-collection/SplayTreeMap-class.html